# Fetching all the contacts in phone using Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2.3

I am developing a Sencha Touch + Cordova application. I need to get all the device contacts in an android phone.

According to the documentation, if we put,

```
options.filter = ""
```

It should return all the contacts of the phone. But it does not work. And if I put some other string as the filter,
for example,

```
options.filter = "A"
```

I get results according to the filter.

Could someone help me to find out what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably not using the latest cordova contact plugin, you can refer to this:

http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/08/11/plugins-release.html

org.apache.cordova.contacts@0.2.12

*fixes .find method when options param is not passed. Will return all contacts on missing options param*